# load Autocad 2016

Tags: software-installation

Have a pc Core i5/8GB DDR4/1TB/2GB Nvidia gaphic dual boot Win 10 and Ubuntu. Autocad 2016 runs in Windows but doesnt on Ubuntu.
Have loaded Wine but it did not run. Also tried Play on Linux but could not run Autocad. Get error at the Dotnet load stage.
Can someone please  guide me to run this successfully. Shall be grateful.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Don't bother with WINE. Nor with Autocad on Linux. It is not intented to run under Linux. [Best you can get from WINE is "gold"](https://appdb.winehq.org/appview.php?iAppId=86) so that is nowhere near good enough and that is not even with the 2016 version. Unless your knowledge about WINE is near perfect, so you can tune internal settings for WINE to makes this work, not going to happen any time soon.

Your best option would be to either dual boot or use Windows virtualized (vmware or virtualbox). "best" as in: less resource used, best performance and best compatibility.

Or (1st link points to the website, 2nd one to [alternativo.net](http://alternativeto.net) where there are a few more alternatives) ...

[Freecad](http://www.freecadweb.org/) - [FreeCAD](http://alternativeto.net/software/freecad/?platform=linux) is a general purpose Open Source 3D CAD/MCAD/CAx/CAE/PLM modeler, aimed directly at mechanical engineering and product design but also fits in a wider range of uses around engineering, such as architecture or other engineering specialties. It is a feature-based parametric modeler with a modular software architecture which makes it easy to provide additional functionality without modifying the core system.

> FreeCAD is based on OpenCasCade, a powerful geometry kernel, features an Open Inventor-compliant 3D scene representation model provided by the Coin 3D library, and a broad python API. The interface is built with Qt. FreeCAD runs exactly the same way on Windows, Mac OSX and Linux platforms.

[LibreCAD](http://api.viglink.com/api/click?format=go&jsonp=vglnk_146918950265910&key=fb09f2e92cf030fed8c1354a2b962829&libId=iqxphrjp01015k7c000DAlbvaco0p&loc=http%3A%2F%2Falternativeto.net%2Fsoftware%2Fcaduntu%2F%3Fplatform%3Dlinux&v=1&out=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.librecad.org%2F&ref=http%3A%2F%2Falternativeto.net%2Fsoftware%2Fautocad%2F%3Fplatform%3Dlinux&title=LibreCAD%20Alternatives%20for%20Linux%20-%20AlternativeTo.net&txt=Official%20Website) - [LibreCAD](http://alternativeto.net/software/caduntu/?platform=linux) (originally QCad then CADuntu) is an open source 2D CAD application for Windows, Apple and Linux. It is based on Qt, which is a leading cross-platform application and UI development framework.

> LibreCAD can read DWG files (and others) as of the latest Nightly build. It writes DXF files, but can also export SVG, JPG, PNG, PDF and other files. It has layers, blocks, splines, polylines, ellipse tools, advanced tangent line & circle tools, transformation tools, an advanced snapping system and more. Because LibreCAD focuses on 2D geometry it is fast and lightweight, with an installer of less than 30mb.